# Elastic search multiple analyzers for one field

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, analyzer, elastic4s

I have a field "name" and I want to analyze it with two analyzers:
  `name typed StringType 
analyzer CustomAnalyzer("partial") 
analyzer CustomAnalyzer("all")`

The problem is that in analyzer function it sets the analyzer one value. The result analyzer will be just "all" custom analyzer. How can I do set these two analyzers to one field?

Comment: The common way to do it is to define a sub-field to your `name` field. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178038/how-to-configure-multiple-analyzers-for-one-field-in-elasticsearch/43178094#43178094

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't support what you want, so Val's suggestion is your best workaround.

Comment: Thank you. I used the subfields